# Expiry alert in Access

Tags: ms-access-2010

how to create expiry alert in Access

for example if I have a gym membership database in access and I want the membership status to show (Expired/Expiring soon or Active membership) according to the starting date and End date.
what condition do I need to insert on the Status field?

I've tried to insert this rule: if [Expiry date]>date()-7,"Expiring soon"

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IIf function:

```
Status: IIf([Expiry date]<Date(),"Expired",IIf([Expiry date]<Date()+7,"Expiring soon","Active membership"))
```

Comment: but what if I need the form to get the data from the query that I used the code you gave me in it, what should I do?

so I have a Start date and End Date and I want the status field to check the End Date and shows one of the previous status according to the comparison between the End Date and today's DATE